# How many ways to pick 11 coins from those five piles of coins which must consists of all five different value of coins

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

If we have a piles of 10 pennies , a pile of 10 nickels, a pile of 10 dimes , a pile of 9 quarters and a pile of 8 half-dollar coins.

How many ways to pick 11 coins from those five piles of coins which must consists of all five different value of coins?

I figured out how to pick 11 coins from five piles of coins:

(5-1 +11)
        C
          (11) = 15 C 11 = 1365

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Usually people don’t answer to questions that show no effort on the questioner’s part because it makes the questioner appear to use this site as a homework help site, which it is not. Please edit your question to show more effort, such as any attempts.

Comment: Chances are that you've already seen problems equivalent to this one and have been given a method to solve them. But the wording of those other problems may have been quite different. So it's a matter of trying to find the equivalence to a problem whose solution you already know.

Comment: I have done the first part and edit it.

Comment: What is $15$ in $15 C11$? $11$ are the coin that you choose, but what is $15$?

Comment: @user525966 That approach is wrong because $\binom{42}{6}$ represents the situation when all the coins are unique.

Answer (score 2):

We can approach this in the following manner:

Let $a$ be the number of pennies chosen,
$b$ be the number of nickels chosen, 
 
$c$ be the number of dimes chosen,
$d$ be the number of quarters chosen,
$e$ be the number of half-dollar coins chosen.

According to the given condition,

$a+b+c+d+e=11$

But $a,b,c,d,e\geq 1$

So, substituting $p=a-1$, $q=b-1$, $r=c-1$, $s=d-1$, $t=e-1$,

We get ,
 $p+q+r+s+t=6$ where $p,q,r,s,t\geq0$

The number of natural solutions will be ${(6+4) \choose 4}$ i.e. $\binom{10}{4} = 210$

We don't even have to worry about whether $a,b,c,d,e$ will exceed their limit of $10,10,10,9,8$ because we have chosen at least one from each pile which gives $max\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ possible $=7$.